# Struggle "of" or "to" return?

Tags: prepositions

I am not sure if there is any difference of meaning between

> Our whole life is a struggle of return to ourselves.

and

> Our whole life is a struggle to return to ourselves.

Are they both correct? Could you explain why any of them is incorrect? Is "return" a noun in the first sentence and a verb in the second?

Comment: For some reason I cannot fully explain the first one sounds awkward to me and almost wrong. The second one seems OK though. It might help to have more context.

Comment: Syntactically, we usually say something is *a struggle **to do** something* (***infinitive*** verb), but it's perfectly possible to say things like *My life is a struggle **of finding** ways to avoid boredom* (***continuous*** verb, functioning as part of a ***noun** phrase*).

Comment: In general, the metaphoric usage ***find oneself*** will be understood as a somewhat "touchy-feely, woolly" way of saying ***come to understand and accept one's inner nature***, but ***return to oneself*** is just hopelessly vague [new-age-speak,](https://www.patheos.com/blogs/companionsonthejourney/2018/03/language-meaning-new-age-wittgenstein/) evoking mysticism and/or "noble savage" philosophy.

Comment: Most such religious contexts are about "advancing" (towards a Paradise set in the future), rather than "returning" (to the Garden of Eden set in the past), but you know best what *you're* trying to say. Whatever - if you're going to qualify "a struggle", you'd usually do that using an ***infinitive verb*** (untensed, complete with ***to***, as in *Life is a struggle **to survive***). My example *(the **struggle of** finding survival strategies)* is "syntactically valid", but it's not particularly idiomatic, so you should probably avoid trying to copy that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example is correct: the difference between the two is that "of return" is referring to return as a noun/gerund (a specific *instance of returning*) versus the infinitive verb "to return", which refers to *the act of returning* in general.

In this context, the operative phrase of your sentence is "life is a struggle". But a struggle to do what? To return to ourselves: *the act of returning* is the struggle, not an instance of returning anywhere specific. The preposition *of* implies that the struggle is "owned" or possessed by the return, whereas the infinitive verb *to return* describes the struggle: the struggle owns the act of returning...the return IS the struggle, which is what you are wanting to say here.

EDIT: And actually, thinking of it more, you could say "...life is a struggle of returning to ourselves" and that would also be correct, since now *the act of* "returning to ourselves" is the direct object being equated to struggle instead of just a *return*, and *ourselves* is no longer the indirect/dative object, but linked by a reflexive present participle (ie "we are returning to ourselves" - we are the subject of that phrase, but it's a [dangling participle](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/dangling-participle.html) because the subject *we* is implied in the context of "our whole life", since we possess our own lives). So adding -ing for "of return*ing*" would work better than leaving it out if you were to use *of*, but "*to* return" is still best because it does not make use of a dangling participle (which is sometimes ok, but that's its own question).

Answer (score 1):

## Your second version just sounds more natural.

None of them are incorrect, per se, and there is nothing wrong with your second version

> Our whole life is a struggle **to return to ourselves**.

Your first version uses "return" as an abstract noun.

> Our whole life is a struggle of return to ourselves.

This is also grammatical—we say "A person *of interest*". However, "return" is harder to read when it is a noun and not a verb.

For instance, we still use "meeting" and not "meet" because "meet" is not distinct as a noun. Therefore, contrasted with the alternative, this version sounds clunky and almost wrong because it is not phrased as follows.

> Our whole life is a struggle of **returning** to ourselves.

Thus, I think the second version sounds simply natural. Though, the first version is a close contender after the rephrasing. If we are being more lenient, they are both grammatical.